# my if condition isn't working properly

Tags: c#, ado.net

am working in C# on ADO.NET, i connected with my database successfully and everything is fine so i put check in side while(reader.Read) to check specefic value but the condition is giving false everytime i try,

```
            string qry = "select * from LoginTB";
            reader = db.select_data(qry);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader["ID"].ToString());// its shows Doctor
                    if (string.Equals(reader["ID"].ToString(), "Doctor"))// why false?!
                    {

                        //flag = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("hello");
                        str = reader[2].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have whitespace at one end or another.

Try changing your MessageBox call to surround the string with quotation marks, or add a .Trim to the comparison:

```
... (reader["ID"].ToString().Trim(), "Doctor") ...
```

Comment: I doubt I would save a man drowning in acid if he called me 'u' to save himself two keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the string "Doctor" doesn't have leading or trailing spaces? You can't really see them if you display it in a MessageBox.

Try

```
MessageBox.Show("-" + reader["ID"] + "-");
```

to see.

See also: [string.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)

Comment: thanks Alot that was the issue, so now i have to do this? reader[0].tostring().trim;

Comment: You should probably find out why your database has strings with extra spaces being written into it.

Comment: What Will Dean said, and also I'd question why your ID column contains strings.

Comment: its string cause in our system normally ID's are like 1472-FAS/BSCS/F06

Comment: @Will Dean: i am trying to fix it you are right it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
reader["ID"].ToString().Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

try , Notice Trim() function

```
while (reader.Read()) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(reader["ID"].ToString());// its shows Doctor 
                if (string.Equals(reader["ID"].ToString().Trim(), "Doctor"))// why false?! 
                { 

                    //flag = true; 
                    MessageBox.Show("hello"); 
                    str = reader[2].ToString(); 
                    break; 
                } 
        }
```

or

```
while (reader.Read()) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(reader["ID"].ToString());// its shows Doctor 
                if (string.compare(reader["ID"].ToString().Trim(), "Doctor",true)==0)// why false?! 
                { 

                    //flag = true; 
                    MessageBox.Show("hello"); 
                    str = reader[2].ToString(); 
                    break; 
                } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the string stored in your database begins or ends with whitespace.

You might want to try:

```
if (String.Equals(reader["ID"].ToString().Trim(), "Doctor")) {
}
```

Or, more clearly:

```
if (reader["ID"].ToString().Trim() == "Doctor")) {
}
```